# Unable to add node_module folder to git

Tags: git, github, gulp, gulp-sass

**I was just setting up environment for gulp and after I did that I tried to create a repo on git after which I was unable to use git add -A so I tried adding the folders separately, I was able to add all the folders other than node_modules and this is the error it shows.**

warning: unable to access 'node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/sass-graph/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/normalize-package-data/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-correct/.gitignore': Filename too long
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/.gitattributes.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/.npmignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/.travis.yml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/Gruntfile.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/LICENSE-MIT.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/README.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/bower.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/component.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/package.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/tests/generate-test-data.py.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/tests/index.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/tests/tests.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/utf8.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/.gitattributes.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/.npmignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/.travis.yml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/Gruntfile.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/LICENSE-MIT.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/README.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/bower.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/component.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/package.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/tests/generate-test-data.py.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/tests/index.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/tests/tests.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/utf8.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
fatal: unable to stat 'node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/normalize-package-data/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-correct/node_modules/spdx-license-ids/spdx-license-ids.json': Filename too long

Comment: Why in the name of Torvalds are you adding `node_modules` to version control? Just add `package.json` to the repo so that others know what packages to pull in, otherwise you're just wasting space, bandwidth, processing, and cluttering your tree. You should be adding `node_modules/` to your global `.gitignore`

Comment: You are right, I am just a new bee trying out new things. Just figured this out today that even if I want to share this repository with anyone then pakage.json would do the job. After cloning one just need to hit npm install and that's pretty much it.

By the way thanks.

Comment: How I can untrack node_modules folder can you please tell?

Comment: Actually I did it thanks. Sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because of the unified line endings.

change setting:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf  false
```

reference:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace

BTW, why did you want to add `node_modules` to git? using `package.json` isn't good?

Comment: You are right, I am just a new bee trying out new things. Just figured this out today that even if I want to share this repository with anyone then pakage.json would do the job. After cloning one just need to hit npm install and that's pretty much it.

By the way thanks.

Comment: How I can untrack node_modules folder can you please tell? I have tried different things but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ImmadHamid you should use a `.gitignore` file to untrack node_modules folder in your git